# Wordpress widget creation

Tags: wordpress, widget

%wordpress I've created to tool to turn php functions into Wordpress widgets. I use the register_sidebar_widget function but it seems like wp_register_sidebar_widget would give me more options. Is that legal?

P.S. I also generate widgets in the new 2.8 format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register_sidebar_widget` is deprecated--though it can still be used, but you could use `wp_register_sidebar_widget`.  If you do use `register_sidebar_widget` might want to bracket it in an `if ( function_exists('register_sidebar_widget') )` in case that function gets removed in subsequent versions.

Also, there is a plugin, Otto's PHP Code Widget, that allows PHP code in a widget.

1. http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets_Api/register_sidebar_widget
2. http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets_Api/wp_register_sidebar_widget
3. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget

Answer (score 0):

Legal? Sure. WordPress is GPL, you can do anything you like as long as you follow the requirements of the license.

Comment: I meant legit I guess. Since my tool will be creating many widgets I want to make sure I'm using the "preferred", "supported", "least likely to break in future versions" way of building widgets.